# Java] How to calculate average score by subjects (using ArrayList)

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to calculate total and average scores by subjects (not by students!). FYI, I wrote this code while I was studying `ArrayList`.

Here's the codes I'm working on. The result I wanna get is `mathTotal: 180, korTotal: 150, engTotal: 90` & `mathAvg: 90, korAvg: 75, engAvg: 90`.

```java
public class Subject {

    private String subjectName;
    private int score;
    
    public Subject(String subjectName, int score) {
        this.subjectName = subjectName;
        this.score = score;
    }
    
    public String getSubName() {
        return subjectName;
    }
    
    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }   
}
```

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Student {
    private int studentID;
    private String studentName;
    ArrayList<Subject> subjectList;
    
    public Student(int studentID, String studentName) {
        this.studentID = studentID;
        this.studentName = studentName;
        subjectList = new ArrayList<Subject>();
    }
    
    public void addSubject(String subjectName, int score) {
        Subject subject = new Subject(subjectName, score);
        
        subjectList.add(subject);
    }
    
    public void calcScore() {
        int total = 0;
        double subCnt = 0;
        
        System.out.println("< "+studentName+"'s score >");
        for (Subject subject: subjectList) {
            total += subject.getScore();
            System.out.println(subject.getSubName()+": "+subject.getScore());
            subCnt++;
        }
        double average = total/subCnt;
        String averageCut = String.format("%.2f", average);
        System.out.println("total: "+total);
        System.out.println("average: "+averageCut);
    }
}
```

```java
public class StudentTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Student student1 = new Student(1001, "Amy Park");
        Student student2 = new Student(1005, "Steven Yeun");
        
        student1.addSubject("Math", 80);
        student1.addSubject("Korean", 90);
        
        student2.addSubject("Math", 100);
        student2.addSubject("Korean", 60);
        student2.addSubject("English", 90);
        
        student1.calcScore();
        student2.calcScore();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From inside the `Student` class you can't get average scores by subjects since each student has a list of subjects. One possibility would be to define an accessor method for the list of subjects (i.e. `Student#getSubjects()` and use that outside of the student class to calculate the statistics by subject. You could also use a map to keep track of your totals, and counts, by subject.

For example:

```
Map<String, Integer> gradeTotalsBySubject = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Integer> countsBySubject = new HashMap<>();
for (student : students) {
    for (subject : student.getSubjects()) {
        int currentGradeTotal = gradeTotalsBySubject.getOrDefault(subject.getName(), 0);
        currentGradeTotal += subject.getScore();
        gradeTotalsBySubject.put(subject.getName(), current);
        int currentCount = countsBySubject.getOrDefault(subject.getName(), 0);
        currentCount++;
        countsBySubject.put(subject.getName(), currentCount);
    }
}
```

This will give you the totals you need, and the numbers to divide by, grouped by subject. At that point you can iterate over the map entries in gradeTotalsBySubject and dividing each value by the count in the corresponding counts map you can get the averages.

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution! Really helped me a lot.

Comment: If you have help you consider accepting an answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You can add a **static HashMap**  inside `Subject` class. And each time you add a new subject, you will have add the subject to the HashMap as a key, and as value will be an `ArrayList` which will contain each score you are adding.

The `Subject` class:

```
class Subject {
private String subjectName;
private int score;
public static HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>> subjectsScores = new HashMap<>();

public Subject(String subjectName, int score) {
    
    
    if(subjectsScores.containsKey(subjectName))
    {
        subjectsScores.get(subjectName).add(score);
    }
    else{
        subjectsScores.put(subjectName,new ArrayList<>(){{add(score);}});
    }
    
    this.subjectName = subjectName;
    this.score = score;
}

public String getSubName() {
    return subjectName;
}

public int getScore() {
    return score;
}   
}
```

> Inside the Constructor, you are adding the correct values to the hashmap.What it does is checking if you already added the subject, if you did it, then, the score will be added to the ArrayList of the current subject: `subjectsScores.get(subjectName).add(score);`. The `subjectName` variable is the current subject you are adding from the main, and `add(score)` corresponds to the ArrayList of the key `subjectName`.

And inside your main class, you can iterate over the hashmap with a foreach, like this:

```
public class StudentTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Student student1 = new Student(1001, "Amy Park");
    Student student2 = new Student(1005, "Steven Yeun");
    
    student1.addSubject("Math", 80);
    student1.addSubject("Korean", 90);
    
    student2.addSubject("Math", 100);
    student2.addSubject("Korean", 60);
    student2.addSubject("English", 90);
    
    student1.calcScore();
    student2.calcScore();
    
    Subject.subjectsScores.forEach((k,v)->{
        
        int total=0;
        
        for(int sc : v)
        {
            total+=sc;
        }
        
        int av = total / v.size();
        
        System.out.printf("Subject: %s -- Total: %d -- Average: %d\n",k,total,av);
        
    }); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed solution!! Always a pleasure to learn something new (;

Answer (score 2):

If you could add getter/setter for Subject List in your Student class, the below code would work for you:

```
public class StudentTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Student student1 = new Student(1001, "Amy Park");
        Student student2 = new Student(1005, "Steven Yeun");

        student1.addSubject("Math", 80);
        student1.addSubject("Korean", 90);

        student2.addSubject("Math", 100);
        student2.addSubject("Korean", 60);
        student2.addSubject("English", 90);

        List<Student> students =new ArrayList<>();
        students.add(student1);
        students.add(student2);

        List<Subject> subjectList = students.stream()
                .flatMap(student -> student.getSubjectList().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        Collector<Subject, ?, Double> avgScoreCollector = Collectors.averagingInt(Subject::getScore);
        Collector<Subject, ?, Integer> totalScoreCollector = Collectors.summingInt(Subject::getScore);
        Map<String, Integer> groupedSubjectsSum =
                subjectList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Subject::getSubName, totalScoreCollector));
        Map<String, Double> groupedSubjectsAvg =
                subjectList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Subject::getSubName, avgScoreCollector));

        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : groupedSubjectsSum.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Sum of " + entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue());
        }
        System.out.println("\n*************************\n");
        for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : groupedSubjectsAvg.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Avg of " + entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Sum of English:90
Sum of Korean:150
Sum of Math:180

*************************

Avg of English:90.0
Avg of Korean:75.0
Avg of Math:90.0
```

In this solution, we are merging all the list of subjects together to form one list and then performing the avg and sum functions on it. Using java8 lambda provides better flexibility to modify and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in earlier answers, in order to get the stats per subject, a static `Map` may be added to `Subject` class to store the scores and facilitate calculation of the total and average scores.

However, since Java 8 there is class [`IntSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html) which can be efficiently used with Stream API to collect such statistics as count, min, max, total, and average values by using [`Collectors.summarizingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summarizingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-)

For example, method `Student::calcScore` may be modified to use this class as follows:

```java
public void calcScore() {
    System.out.printf("< %s's score >%n", studentName);

    IntSummaryStatistics stats = subjectList.stream() // Stream<Subject>
            // print each subject while collecting stats
            .peek(subject -> System.out.printf("%-10s:\t%4d%n",    
                    subject.getSubjectName(), subject.getScore()))
            .collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(Subject::getScore));

    // print stats
    System.out.println("-".repeat(12 + studentName.length()));
    System.out.printf("%-10s:\t%4d%n", "TOTAL", stats.getSum());
    System.out.printf("%-10s:\t%7.2f%n", "AVERAGE", stats.getAverage());
    System.out.println("=".repeat(12 + studentName.length()));
}
```

And class `Subject` may be updated as follows to utilize `IntSummaryStatistics`:

```java
public class Subject {
    private String subjectName;
    private int score;
    private static Map<String, List<Integer>> rawScoresBySubject = new TreeMap<>();

    public Subject(String subjectName, int score) {
        this.subjectName = subjectName;
        this.score = score;

        rawScoresBySubject
            .computeIfAbsent(subjectName, (key) -> new ArrayList<>())
            .add(score);
    }

    public static Map<String, IntSummaryStatistics> getStats() {
        return rawScoresBySubject.entrySet().stream() // Stream<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                e -> e.getValue().stream() // Stream<Integer>
                    .collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(Integer::intValue))
                ));
    }

    // getters/setters
}
```

Here a `TreeMap` is used to provide sorting by `subjectName`.  Also, the map is populated using `computeIfAbsent` method which allows to add an initial value (in this case it's an empty `ArrayList`) and use this value immediately by adding the score.

The test:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student student1 = new Student(1001, "Amy Park");
    Student student2 = new Student(1005, "Steven Yeun");

    student1.addSubject("Math", 80);
    student1.addSubject("Korean", 90);

    student2.addSubject("Math", 100);
    student2.addSubject("Korean", 60);
    student2.addSubject("English", 90);

    student1.calcScore();
    student2.calcScore();

    Subject.getStats()
            .forEach((subject, stats) ->
                System.out.printf("%-10s:\t%7.2f\t%4d / %d%n",
                    subject, stats.getAverage(), stats.getSum(), stats.getCount()
            ));
}
```

Output:

```
< Amy Park's score >
Math      :   80
Korean    :   90
--------------------
TOTAL     :  170
AVERAGE   :   85.00
====================
< Steven Yeun's score >
Math      :  100
Korean    :   60
English   :   90
-----------------------
TOTAL     :  250
AVERAGE   :   83.33
=======================
English   :   90.00   90 / 1
Korean    :   75.00  150 / 2
Math      :   90.00  180 / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think first of all you have to modify your design. I offer to add `School` abstraction to hold `Student` list and calculations:

```java
public final class School {

    private final List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        students.add(student);
    }

    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(students);
    }

    public Map<String, Double> calcAverageScoreBySubject() {
        Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<>();

        getScoresBySubject().forEach((subjectName, scores) ->
                map.put(subjectName, scores.stream()
                                           .mapToDouble(Integer::doubleValue)
                                           .average().orElse(0)));

        return map;
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> calcTotalScoreBySubject() {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        getScoresBySubject().forEach((subjectName, scores) ->
                map.put(subjectName, scores.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).sum()));

        return map;
    }

    private Map<String, List<Integer>> getScoresBySubject() {
        Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();

        students.stream()
                .map(Student::getSubjects)
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .forEach(subject -> {
                    if (!map.containsKey(subject.getName()))
                        map.put(subject.getName(), new ArrayList<>());
                    map.get(subject.getName()).add(subject.score);
                });

        return map;
    }
}
```

Then you should use **unmodifiable** objects for `Student` and `Subject`:

```java
public static final class Subject {

    private final String name;
    private final int score;

    public Subject(String name, int score) {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }
}
```

```java
public final class Student {

    private final int id;
    private final String name;
    private final List<Subject> subjects = new ArrayList<>();

    public Student(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void addSubject(Subject subject) {
        subjects.add(subject);
    }

    public List<Subject> getSubjects() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(subjects);
    }
}
```

And finally your test could look like this:

```java
public class StudentTest {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        School school = new School();
        school.addStudent(amyPark());
        school.addStudent(stevenYeun());

        Map<String, Double> subjectNameAverageScore = school.calcAverageScoreBySubject();
        Map<String, Integer> subjectNameTotalScore = school.calcTotalScoreBySubject();

        school.getStudents().forEach(student -> {
            System.out.format("< %d: %s's core >\n", student.getId(), student.getName());

            student.getSubjects().forEach(subject -> {
                String subjectName = subject.getName();
                int score = subject.getScore();
                int total = subjectNameTotalScore.get(subjectName);
                double average = subjectNameAverageScore.get(subjectName);
                System.out.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%s: %d (subject - total: %d, average: %.1f)\n", subjectName, score, total, average);
            });

            System.out.println();
        });
    }

    private static Student amyPark() {
        Student student = new Student(1001, "Amy Park");
        student.addSubject(new Subject("Math", 80));
        student.addSubject(new Subject("Korean", 90));
        return student;
    }

    private static Student stevenYeun() {
        Student student = new Student(1005, "Steven Yeun");
        student.addSubject(new Subject("Math", 100));
        student.addSubject(new Subject("Korean", 60));
        student.addSubject(new Subject("English", 90));
        return student;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
< 1001: Amy Park's core >
Math: 80 (subject - total: 180, average: 90.0)
Korean: 90 (subject - total: 150, average: 75.0)

< 1005: Steven Yeun's core >
Math: 100 (subject - total: 180, average: 90.0)
Korean: 60 (subject - total: 150, average: 75.0)
English: 90 (subject - total: 90, average: 90.0)
```